# How to show convergence with respect to $\left|\cdot\right|_{p}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am having a difficulty showing convergence or divergence with respect to $\left|\cdot\right|_{p}:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}\cup\left\{ \infty\right\}$ 
  where $a=p^{n}\frac{a'}{b'}\to p^{-n}$
 . I want to show (1) $\left\{ \frac{1}{10^{n}}\right\}$ 
  diverges for any prime $p$
  and (2) $\left\{ a^{p^{n}}\right\}$ 
  converges for any $p$
  where $\left(a,p\right)=1$
 . For the first question, I see that for $p=2$
  or $5$, $$\left|\frac{1}{10^{n}}\right|_{p}=p^{n}\to\infty.$$
 However, for the other case of (1) I don't know. I am having a tough time seeing the intuition behind it. As for question (2), I don't see why that sequence necessarily converges. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) If $10^{-n}\to x$ then $10x=x$. Is $x=0$ possible? (Hint: $|\cdot|_p$ is continuous.)

(2) Hint: $a^{p^n}$ converges iff $a^{p^{n+1}}-a^{p^n}=a^{p^n}(a^{(p-1)p^n}-1)$ converges to $0$.

(See [Teichmüller character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_character) for more information.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (1): if $(10,p)=1$, choose a power $p^e$ of $p$ such that $10$ generates a non-trivial cyclic subgroup of $\mathbf Z/p^e\mathbf Z$, say of order $d>1$. Then show that the sequence $\{1/10^n\} \subseteq \mathbf Z_p$ is periodic of period $d$ when reduced modulo $p^e$, hence cannot converge.

Hint for (2): show that it is Cauchy. Use the description of the multiplicative group of $\mathbf Z/p^e\mathbf Z$.